# Craft advanced routing is not working

Tags: craft4, routing

this is my ContactController.php in controller/ folder.

```
<?php


namespace controllers;
use craft\web\Controller;
use yii\web\Response;

class ContactController extends Controller
{
    public function actionSubmit(): Response
    {
        dd('test');
    
    }
}
```

this is my routes.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Site URL Rules
 *
 * You can define custom site URL rules here, which Craft will check in addition
 * to routes defined in Settings → Routes.
 *
 * Read all about Craft’s routing behavior, here:
 * https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/routing.html
 */

return [

    'contact' => 'controllers/contact/submit',
];
```

I cant access *http://127.0.0.1:65009/contact* says 404!

Can anyone help me I am new in craft.